# how to make elastic search to "NOT" increase scores if multiple were matched

Tags: elasticsearch

consider this:

```
doc1-->
{
   "content":{"one"}
}

doc2-->
{
   "content": {"one one one one two two"}
}

doc3-->
{
   "content": {"one one"}
}
```

if I query this  as :

```
{endpoint}/_search?q=one+two
```

my scores would be :

> (doc2)6,(doc3)2,(doc1)1

my question is how I can query this so my scores would ignore duplicates and be flatted to:

> (doc2)2,(doc3)1,(doc1)1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is to disable term frequency in scoring. 
You can disable it in the mapping.

You can find how to do it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#tf).

Comment: I c, well there are other services that are dependant on using this, if I add it to mapping the those services get affected, right?

Comment: Only thing that is going to change is the scoring logic for query on this field alone.